# Is there a measure of similarity for economies?

Tags: international-economics

Is there a measure of similarity for economies?

For example, I would like to find the world economies most similar to the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't. Ant that is actually a good thing, the economic structure of a country is usually a fairly complicated thing to be able to simplify it with a single number. You could, on the other hand, create an aggregate of measurements and try to look for patterns, e.g. you can see the behavior of macroeconomic variables such as [gdp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)_per_capita), [inflation rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_inflation_rate) and [unemployment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_unemployment_rate), and based on those decide which countries are similar to each other.

And that is why [clustering analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) is for. In the plot below I used Principal Component Analysis (just to reduce the dimensionality of the problem and be able to graphically display what's going on) to show 4 clusters fo countries. Each color is a [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) cluster, the axis are just the two firs principal components $x_1$ and $x_2$

[image]

I also added some of the countries on each cluster so you can see their similarity. For example, the $\color{blue}{\rm blue}$ cluster has large gdp, low unemployment, whereas countries in the $\color{green}{\rm green}$ cluster are not doing so well: high inflation, high unemployment and low gdp.

The cluster that you are interested in has these values (as of 2017)

```
                 country     gdp  inflation  unemployment
---------------------------------------------------------
9              Australia   55692       1.95           5.3
13               Austria   47347       2.08           5.1
17               Belgium   43488       2.13           6.2
15                Canada   45094       1.60           5.6
8                Denmark   56630       1.15           4.8
14               Finland   45927       0.75           7.2
20                France   39932       1.03           8.9
16               Germany   44769       1.74           3.3
3                Iceland   70248       1.76           2.9
4                Ireland   68710       0.34           5.3
19                Israel   40272       0.24           3.7
22                 Japan   38448       0.47           2.4
0             Luxembourg  105863       1.73           5.0
11           Netherlands   48555       1.38           3.5
18           New Zealand   41572       1.85           3.9
2                 Norway   75389       1.88           4.0
5                  Qatar   61024       0.40           0.6
12            San Marino   47595       1.05           8.0
10                Sweden   52925       1.79           6.3
1            Switzerland   80637       0.53           2.4
23  United Arab Emirates   37732       1.97           1.6
21        United Kingdom   39800       2.69           4.0
6          United States   59792       2.13           3.9
```